# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ScriptUtils in osgi bundle

Tags: java, java-8, osgi, apache-karaf, nashorn

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager(null);
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
BundleContext context = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(FormulaImpl.class).getBundleContext();
URL configURL = context.getBundle().getEntry("eval.txt");
if (configURL != null) {
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = configURL.openStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
        }
        engine.eval(out.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

Object obj = engine.get("formulaColumn");
```

In this code, obj is getting as object array.
I can not convert into object.
In java 1.7 using Rhino object is getting.
I tried with

```
Object obj = (Object)ScriptUtils.convert(engine.get("formulaColumn"), Object.class);
```

But No calssDef error showing in java 1.8

I am using osgi. I exported jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptUtils  .
From my jsfile i am returning an array.

Comment: Your question is barely readable. NoClassDefFoundError means that you don't have the necessary class in your classpath, add the missing jar to your buildpath

Comment: Could you post the full stackTrace? It seems unlikely you're missing the ScriptUtils class since it is included in the JDK.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ScriptUtils
Error is showing.
I added jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ScriptUtils . But runtime it can not get.

Comment: In java 1.7 using Rhino i am getting correct.
Object obj = engine.get("formulaColumn");

Comment: I added  jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.* in Export tag in pom.xml also

Comment: Looking at [this oracle article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html)( scroll down to the "Embedding Oracle Nashorn" section), it looks like you should be using classes from `javax.script` rather than `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting`

Comment: i am using javax.script .

Comment: Object obj = engine.get("formulaColumn"); // getiing object array in nashorn(java 1.8)
For getting object i tried with
Object obj = (Object)ScriptUtils.convert(engine.get("formulaColumn"), Object.class);
This line throw error like class Nodef found

Comment: I am using osgi . I export jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.Still it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't have to use ScriptUtils.convert() method in your java code, if you are returning your data from java script as follows:

return Java.to(data,"java.lang.Object")

I hope, this would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Shemeem.
I added return type as Java.to(data,"java.lang.Object") in js file and it is working.